# How to add 3x3 row of buttons between my slider and floatingbutton

Tags: flutter, dart

as the title says I want to add a 3x3 buttons grid, but I'm not able to do, I don't understand how to create all of this elements
(I'm thinking in a div way like in html)

Here is my code, at top is my carousel slider and at the bottom is the floatingbutton, I need my 3x3 to be below my carousel slider and top of my floating button

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',

];

void main() => runApp(CarouselDemo());

final themeMode = ValueNotifier(2);

class CarouselDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      builder: (context, value, g) {
        return MaterialApp(
          initialRoute: '/',
          darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
          themeMode: ThemeMode.values.toList()[value as int],
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          routes: {
            '/': (ctx) => ComplicatedImageDemo(),
          },
        );
      },
      valueListenable: themeMode,
    );
  }
}

class DemoItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String route;
  DemoItem(this.title, this.route);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(title),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, route);
      },
    );
  }
}

final List<Widget> imageSliders = imgList
    .map((item) => Container(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(item, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0.0,
                      left: 0.0,
                      right: 0.0,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                              Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                            ],
                            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            end: Alignment.topCenter,
                          ),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'No. ${imgList.indexOf(item)} image',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        ))
    .toList();

class ComplicatedImageDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Sayapp 0.2')),
      body: Container(
        child: CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            autoPlay: true,
            aspectRatio: 2.0,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
          ),
          items: imageSliders,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {},
        label: Text('Alert'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.add_alert_sharp),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Here is my idea]

Comment: Can you share a quick mock of what you want to obtain? just to better understand which kind of design you need

Comment: Sure, I'll be updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body: Column(
  children: [
    Container(
        child: CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            autoPlay: true,
            aspectRatio: 2.0,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
          ),
          items: imageSliders,
        ),
      ),
    Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Button1();
            Button2();
            Button3();
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Button1();
            Button2();
            Button3();
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Button1();
            Button2();
            Button3();
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: So my problem was the Scaffold? @liams piegel

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridView.builder() to do this

```
List<Widget> buttonList = [Button1(),Button2(),Button3(),Button4(),Button5(),Button6(),Button7(),Button8(),Button9()];
// inside body
    body: Column(
  children: [
      CarouselSlider(
        options: CarouselOptions(
         autoPlay: true,
         aspectRatio: 2.0,
         enlargeCenterPage: true,
       ),
      items: imageSliders,
     ),
GridView.builder(
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 3,   // number of widgets in a row
      crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
      childAspectRatio: (1.0 / 1.2),
    ),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return buttonList[index];
    },
    itemCount: buttonList.length,
  ),
],)
```